# Google Assistant API generating .proto file missing import

Tags: android, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I am getting the errors

```
google/api/http.proto: File not found
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found
```

when trying to generate the .java files for embedded_assistant.proto. I am using the [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) for Android.

Where do I find the descriptor.proto file as I do not find it anywhere on the Google API [github](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing descriptor.proto for Android is [protobuf issue 1889](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1889). The workaround is to add a `protobuf` dependency on the full protobuf library:

```
dependencies {
  protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'
}
```